# php expiry date traffic light system

Tags: php, mysql, css

I am working on a traffic light system. It's in a bit of a mess and it's not working the way it should.

My aim is to get the system working like so;

In the database there are dates of when a supplier's insurance is due to expire. If the date of expiry is 30 days away or less then I want these dates to be pulled through and echoed out, but others which expire after 30 days should not be shown.

At the moment it also gives the number of days until the expiry date, but this doesn't work correctly, so say today was the 2nd of May and tomorrow is the 3rd; the insurance document is due to expire on the 3rd, so it should say insurance expires tomorrow. This is currently not working correctly and I'm getting something like '2 days' till expiry instead of 'expires tomorrow'

Like wise if the insurance was due to expire today it should say expires today but its not getting the days right.

Also, i have designed diffrent coloured div tags to show as a sort of traffic light signal depending on which dates the insurance docs expire. If a document is due to expire within 30 to 20 days i want my green div to display, else if a document is due to expire in 19-7 days i want it to show as amber, if a document is due to expire 7-0 days or is over due it should be red.

Here is my code, please can someone show me how i could improve it to do what i need it to do, thanks

CODE:

```
    <?php include 'config.php';
         $data = mysql_query("SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, insurance_date, NOW()) AS expire_date FROM supplier_stats") 
         or die(mysql_error()); 

         echo "<table class=\"table\" style=\"width:995px;  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
         font-size:11px;\" >

    <tr>
        <td style=\"width:100px;\">ID:</td><td>Company Name:</td><td>Company Reg No:</td><td>Owner:</td><td style=\"width:200px;\">Note:</td><td style=\"width:100px;\">Date:</td><td>Status:</td></tr>";


         while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { 
           $days = $row['expire_date'] -1;


           echo "<tr><td style=\"width:100px;\"><p>".$row['id'] . "</p></td>"; 
           echo "<td style=\"width:150px;\"><p>".$row['company_name'] . "</p></td>"; 
           echo "<td style=\"width:150px;\"><p>".$row['company_reg_number'] . "</p></td>";
           echo "<td style=\"width:100px;\"><p>".$row['owner'] . "</p></td>";

           if ($days > 0) {
                echo "<td style=\"width:200px;\"><p>Insurance expires in <font color=\"red\">{$row['expire_date']} day(s)!</font></p></td>"; 
            } else {
              $when = $days*-1;           

              echo "<td style=\"width:200px;\"><p>Insurance expires";

              if ($when > 1){
                  echo " in <font color=\"red\">{$when} days</font></p></td>";

              } elseif ($when < 1) {
                echo "<font color=\"red\"> tomorrow!</font></td>";
              }
            elseif ($when == 0) 
            {
                echo " today!</font></p></td>";
            }

            echo "<td>";
              echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($row['insurance_date']));   

      echo"</td>";


            }
            if ($when >= 20){
                echo "<td style=\"width:150px;\"><div class=\"green_light\"></div></td>";
              }

              if ($when >= 7){
                echo "<td style=\"width:150px;\"><div class=\"amber_light\"></div></td>";
              }

 if ($when <= 7){
                echo "<td style=\"width:150px;\"><div class=\"red_light\"></div></td>";
              }


            echo "<tr>";
          }


          echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML


        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the query to accurately reflect the days before the expiry_date then it should simplify the checking. The query below truncates to the day and gives accurate days_before_expires as positive numbers.

positive numbers are days before. so +1 means ends tomorrow.

zero means ends today

negative numbers means it has expired.

```
SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,  CURRENT_DATE(), DATE(insurance_date)) AS days_before_expires FROM supplier_stats
```

Converted to 'mysqli'.

All the code has been tested. It implements the 'traffic light' status. I have changed the formatting code to try and make it more maintainable by using functions to calculate an 'urgency indicator'. All the formatting is now done using css.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">
    <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
    <title>23424062/php-expiry-date-traffic-light-system</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            width:995px;
            font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size:11px;
        }
        th {text-align: left; }
        .width_small {
            width: 100px;
        }

        .width_medium {
            width: 150px;
        }

        .width_large {
            width: 200px;
        }
        .urgency_1 {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 6em;
            background-color: green;
            color: yellow;
            padding-left: 1em;
        }
        .urgency_2 {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 6em;
            background-color: orange;
            padding-left: 1em;
        }
        .urgency_3 {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 6em;
            background-color:  red;
            color: yellow;
            padding-left: 1em;
        }

        .green_light {
            width: 3em;
            background-color: green;
        }
        .amber_light {
            width: 3em;
            background-color: orange;
        }
        .red_light {
            width: 3em;
            background-color:  red;
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'test', 'test', 'testmysql');


$data = $mysqli->query("SELECT *, "
                       ." TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,  CURRENT_DATE(), DATE(insurance_date)) AS days_before_expires, "
                       ." DATE(insurance_date) as insurance_day "
                       ." FROM supplier_stats  order by DATE(insurance_date)")
  or die(mysql_error());
?>
<table>
<tr><th class="width_small">ID:</th><th>Company Name:</th><th>Company Reg No:</th><th>Owner:</th><th class="width_large">Note:</th><th class="width_small">Date:</th><th>Status:</th></tr>

<?php while($row = $data->fetch_array()): ?>
    <?php $daysLeft = $row['days_before_expires']; ?>
    <?php $urgency = getUrgency($daysLeft); ?>
    <?php $cssTrafficLight = selectUrgencyLit($row['days_before_expires'],
                                       array('', 'green_light', 'amber_light', 'red_light')); ?>
    <?php $cssUrgency = selectUrgencyLit($row['days_before_expires'],
                                       array('urgency_0', 'urgency_1', 'urgency_2', 'urgency_3')); ?>
    <?php $daysLeftLit = getDaysLeftLiteral($daysLeft); ?>

    <tr><td class="width_small"><p><?= $row['id'] ?></p></td>
    <td class="width_medium"><p><?= $row['company_name'] ?></p></td>
    <td class="width_medium"><p><?= $row['company_reg_number'] ?></p></td>
    <td class="width_small"><p><?= $row['owner'] ?></p></td>
    <td class="width_large"><?= $daysLeftLit; ?></td>

    <td class="width_small"><?= date('d/m/Y',strtotime($row['insurance_day'])) ?></td>
    <td class="width_medium"><div class="<?= $cssTrafficLight?>">&nbsp;</div></td>
    <tr>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  </table> <!-- Close the table in HTML -->
  </body>
</html>

    <?php
/*
 * To tidy the code up and hopefully make it easier to maintain we need
 * a couple of functions...
 *
 * How about assigning an 'urgency level' to each record depending on the
 * days left before the expiry date. The level is as follows:
 *
 * 0 => not urgent  (more than 20 days)
 * 1 => need to pay attention (14 - 20)
 * 2 => soon (7 - 13)
 * 3 => now  (0 - 6)
 */
function getUrgency($daysLeft)
{
    if ($daysLeft >= 21 || $daysLeft < 0) { return 0; }
    if ($daysLeft >= 14  && $daysLeft <= 20) { return 1; }
    if ($daysLeft >=  7  && $daysLeft <= 13) { return 2; }
    return 3;
}

// return a literal depending on the urgency
function selectUrgencyLit($daysLeft, array $litArray)
{
    $urgency = getUrgency($daysLeft);
    if (!empty($litArray[$urgency])) {
        return $litArray[$urgency];
    }
    return '';
}

// return the days left literal
function getDaysLeftLiteral($daysLeft)
{
    $urgency = getUrgency($daysLeft);
    if ($urgency <= 0) {
       return '&nbsp;';
    }

     $text = "Insurance Expires: <div class=\"urgency_{$urgency}\">";

    // set the day literal to be shown
    if  ($daysLeft == 0) { $dayLit = 'today'; }
    elseif ($daysLeft == 1)  { $dayLit = 'tomorrow'; }
    elseif ($daysLeft >= 0 && $daysLeft <= 20)  { $dayLit = "in {$daysLeft} days"; }
    else { $dayLit = '&nbsp;'; }

    return $text . $dayLit .'</div>';
}
```